# MariaDb crashes when "show fields from <table>" is being executed

Tags: innodb, mariadb

A mariadb/mysql 10.5.11 database crashed, and I am trying to recover it with the following docker compose file:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb:10.5.11
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - './ncdb/data:/var/lib/mysql'
      - './my_custom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my_custom.cnf:ro'
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - BITNAMI_DEBUG=true
      - MARIADB_USER=nextcloud
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=xxx
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx
```

The database is starting and I can execute commands such as `SELECT * FROM nextcloud.oc_users`.

Also `mysqlcheck --optimize --all-databases` and `mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases` runs fine.

However, when I try to use `mysqldump --quick` the database server crashes.
I looked further into it and either a `LOCK TABLES` statement or `SHOW FIELDS FROM <table>` statement crash the database server.

Below is the log output when trying to `show fields from oc_users`:

Output from command:

```
docker exec -it mariadb mysql -uroot -p"xxx" nextcloud -e "show fields from oc_users;"
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 1: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Output from database server:

```
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.5.11+maria~focal started.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.11-MariaDB-1:10.5.11+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] mysqld: Aria engine: starting recovery
mariadb  | recovered pages: 0% 11% 23% 36% 47% 59% 70% 80% 90% 100% (0.1 seconds); tables to flush: 1 0
mariadb  |  (0.0 seconds);
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] mysqld: Aria engine: recovery done
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 10737418240, chunk size = 134217728
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=62012988940,62014053874
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './nextcloud/#sql-alter-1-3.ibd' with space ID 417. Another data file called ./nextcloud/oc_filecache.ibd exists with the same space ID.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './nextcloud/#sql-alter-1-3.ibd' with space ID 417. Another data file called ./nextcloud/oc_filecache.ibd exists with the same space ID.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './nextcloud/#sql-alter-1-3.ibd' with space ID 417. Another data file called ./nextcloud/oc_filecache.ibd exists with the same space ID.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './nextcloud/#sql-alter-1-3.ibd' with space ID 417. Another data file called ./nextcloud/oc_filecache.ibd exists with the same space ID.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './nextcloud/#sql-alter-1-3.ibd' with space ID 417. Another data file called ./nextcloud/oc_filecache.ibd exists with the same space ID.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './nextcloud/#sql-alter-1-3.ibd' with space ID 417. Another data file called ./nextcloud/oc_filecache.ibd exists with the same space ID.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './nextcloud/#sql-alter-1-3.ibd' with space ID 417. Another data file called ./nextcloud/oc_filecache.ibd exists with the same space ID.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './nextcloud/#sql-alter-1-3.ibd' with space ID 417. Another data file called ./nextcloud/oc_filecache.ibd exists with the same space ID.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 4122 pages from redo log.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.11 started; log sequence number 62039040909; transaction id 35385299
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/plugin'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/servers'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/db'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/proxies_priv'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/roles_mapping'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/global_priv'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@my-nextcloud-mariadb-0' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/time_zone_leap_second'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/time_zone_name'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210707 19:44:09
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/time_zone'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/time_zone_transition_type'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/time_zone_transition'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/func'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Zerofilling moved table:  './mysql/event'
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
mariadb  | 2021-07-07 19:44:09 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mariadb  | Version: '10.5.11-MariaDB-1:10.5.11+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
mariadb  | 210707 19:57:55 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
mariadb  | This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
mariadb  | or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
mariadb  | or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
mariadb  |
mariadb  | To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
mariadb  |
mariadb  | We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
mariadb  | diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
mariadb  | something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
mariadb  |
mariadb  | Server version: 10.5.11-MariaDB-1:10.5.11+maria~focal
mariadb  | key_buffer_size=134217728
mariadb  | read_buffer_size=131072
mariadb  | max_used_connections=1
mariadb  | max_threads=12
mariadb  | thread_count=1
mariadb  | It is possible that mysqld could use up to
mariadb  | key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 157464 K  bytes of memory
mariadb  | Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
mariadb  |
mariadb  | Thread pointer: 0x7f4f4c010448
mariadb  | Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
mariadb  | where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
mariadb  | terribly wrong...
mariadb  | stack_bottom = 0x7f52341c7d58 thread_stack 0x49000
mariadb  | mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x32)[0x5587ea5e3e22]
mariadb  | Printing to addr2line failed
mariadb  | mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x485)[0x5587ea036a35]
mariadb  | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x153c0)[0x7f5236a773c0]
mariadb  |
mariadb  | Trying to get some variables.
mariadb  | Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
mariadb  | Query (0x7f4f4c029ca0): show fields from oc_users
mariadb  |
mariadb  | Connection ID (thread ID): 5
mariadb  | Status: NOT_KILLED
mariadb  |
mariadb  | Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=on,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on,condition_pushdown_for_subquery=on,rowid_filter=on,condition_pushdown_from_having=on,not_null_range_scan=off
mariadb  |
mariadb  | The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
mariadb  | information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
mariadb  | Writing a core file...
mariadb  | Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
mariadb  | Resource Limits:
mariadb  | Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
mariadb  | Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
mariadb  | Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
mariadb  | Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
mariadb  | Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
mariadb  | Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
mariadb  | Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
mariadb  | Max processes             unlimited            unlimited            processes
mariadb  | Max open files            1048576              1048576              files
mariadb  | Max locked memory         83968000             83968000             bytes
mariadb  | Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
mariadb  | Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
mariadb  | Max pending signals       102292               102292               signals
mariadb  | Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
mariadb  | Max nice priority         0                    0
mariadb  | Max realtime priority     0                    0
mariadb  | Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
mariadb  | Core pattern: core
mariadb  |
mariadb exited with code 139
```

This is my custom config file:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery=0
net_read_timeout=120
net_write_timeout=900
max_allowed_packet=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G
max_connections=10
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=1G
```

I've tried to use the innodb recovery without any luck.
The database has plenty of memory available (24GB).

Comment: Unless you want to spend the rest of the summer trying to debug the segmentation fault, you will probably get better results restoring it from a backup.

Comment: Did that already. I'm just interested if there is a way to recover from this. Specifically because all data seems to be available and all tables OK.

Comment: "all data seems to be available and all tables OK" -- this is somewhat contradicted by your experience with `mysqldump` and `show fields`, isn't it.

Comment: As I said, all SELECT * FROM even UPDATE and DELETES are working fine. It seems more "metadata" related.

Comment: If you are not using MyISAM, don't bother running that`mysqlcheck`.